# Deformation Vs. Blow up

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, birational-geometry

Consider a surface $X$ (which is a projective variety over $\mathbb{C}$) with a double point singularity. To make $X$ smooth, we can either blow up the singularity with a $(-2)$ - curve ($\hat{X}$), or we can simply deform the variety's defining relation ($\tilde{X}$).

In principle, $\hat{X}$ and $\tilde{X}$ are birational to each other (we can find a Zariski open set in both of them that are isomorphic), so we can start from either of them and after a sequence of blow-ups and blow downs get the other one.

I'm wondering whether it's possible to find this sequence of blow-ups and blow downs explicitly...

Maybe it's difficult to answer generally, but I appreciate if you let me know any example that you are aware of...

Comment: If you deform a nodal quartic in $\mathbb{P}^3$ to a smooth quartic, the resulting surface will be in general *not* birational to the nodal one. In fact, you can deform the nodal quartic to *every* smooth quartic, since the deformation space of quartics is connected. And the moduli space of quartics has dimension $19$.

Comment: In general, it is *false* that deforming equations produce birational varieties. Typical example: a nodal cubic curve is rational, but you can deform it to a smooth cubic curve, that has genus $1$.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. About the first comment, I still don't understand why they are not birational. For the second comment, I thought it's the arithmetic genus that is supposed to stay invariant under birational transformation, isn't it?

Comment: **(1)** This is a general fact about moduli of surfaces in $\mathbb{P}^3$, you can have a look in Sernesi book on deformation theory. **(2)** The example of cubic curves in fact shows that the *geometric* genus is not deformation invariant (but it is a birational invariant). Concerning the arithmetic genus, it is both deformation and birationally invariant.

Comment: When you smooth the singularity via a deformation, you must deform the complex structure globally --- thus there is (typically) no open set in the deformed guy isomorphic to an open set in the original guy.

Comment: Since you are a student in string theory, maybe it would be worth framing this as follows: smoothing the node is changing complex moduli, resolving the node is changing Kahler moduli. These two operations are in some sense dual to each other under mirror symmetry. This is literally true one dimension higher where one can either resolve or smooth a conifold singularity --- you are describing the 2D version of a conifold transition.

Comment: Exactly. What I had in mind was in conifold transitions (3D), we usually blow down 2-cycles and blow up 3-cycles (due to deformation). My naive imagination was probably in 2D also deformation can be seen as blowing up some cycles (or at least I wanted to be like that.)

Comment: The ultimate reason I'm asking such questions, is that I wanted to see how Derived categories of these spaces are related after deformations. Since the result is well known for 3D birational transforms (using flops, and MMP), I hoped maybe I can consider the 2D deformation as some kind of birational transformation.

Comment: I don't know what you are looking for in terms of relating derived categories after deformations. These deformations will typically deform the derived category as well. The same is true in dimension three --- if you do a flop on a (-1,-1) curve, you will get an equivalent derived category, but if you do a conifold transition (contract and deform) you will change the derived category. Be careful that you are not confusing deformations with birational transformations.

Comment: One statement about derived categories which is true is the following. Let $X$ be the surface with the double point singularity, let $\hat{X}$ be is its minimal resolution, and let $\mathcal{X}$ be the orbifold (i.e. smooth Deligne-Mumford stack) whose coarse space is $X$. Then $D(\hat{X})$ is equivalent to $D(\mathcal{X})$.